# Debugging python in docker container with pycharm

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

Hey folks I am trying to debug my python code that I wrote in my pycharm professional IDEA and while I can seemingly connect to the container when I run the Debug it tries to pull from the registry (not my local registry that I can pull from).

The error I get is :
Cant create python SDK
 Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.1:53: server misbehaving

Any Idea what i'm configuring wrong (i'm on an isolated enviroment so I cant connect to docker hub)